# Datepicker in div not working after ajax call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, datepicker

I have buttons each with their id (idroom).

When I click on the ajax call is executed, and a datepicker is displayed with the disabled days of that ID.

The problem is that the first click works, the datepicker Shows, but then if I press another button, the datepicker is not displayed

The code with buttons and div datepicker

```
<div class="form-control" style="height: 224px;">
<div type="text" id="datepicker9" name"datepicker9" /></div>
</div>

<?php
include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
$user_id=null;
$sql1= "select h.id_habitacion,h.valor_habitacion,h.obs,
h.id_residencial,r.id_residencial,r.nombre_residencial,
h.id_tipo,t.id_tipo,t.tipo,
h.numero_habitacion,
h.id_tipo,h.tipo_bano,h.estado,h.imagen
from habitaciones as h 
inner join residenciales as r ON h.id_residencial=r.id_residencial 
inner join tipo_habitacion as t ON h.id_tipo=t.id_tipo order by h.id_habitacion";
$query = $con->query($sql1);
if($query->num_rows>0){
while ($r=$query->fetch_array()){
?>
<div style="float:left;border-top-width: 5px;margin-right: 5px;margin-bottom: 5px;margin-left: 5px;margin-top: 5px;" >
<button type='submit' id='buttonValue'  name='buttonValue' onClick='MCNdetails(this)'  value='<?php echo $r["id_habitacion"]?>'  class="<?php if ($r["estado"] == 'Abierta') { echo 'btn btn-sm btn-success'; } elseif ($r["estado"] == 'Cerrada') { echo 'btn btn-sm btn-danger'; }?> label-mini">
N&deg;<?php echo $r["numero_habitacion"]; ?> <?php echo $r["nombre_residencial"]; ?><br><?php echo $r["estado"]; ?>
</button>
</div>
<?php
}}
?>
```

AJAX:

```
<script>
function MCNdetails(btn) {
var buttonValue = btn.value;
        $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'GUImostrarcalendario.php',
                data:'buttonValue='+buttonValue,
                success:function(html){
                $("#datepicker9").html(html);
                }   
 }); 
}
</script>
```

GUImostrarcalendario.php:

```
<?php
    include "controlreservas/conexion.php";
    $id_habitacion=$_POST["buttonValue"];
    $sql1="SELECT llegada,salida,id_reserva FROM reservas where id_habitacion ='$id_habitacion'";
    $query = $con->query($sql1);
    $dates_ar = [];
    if($query->num_rows>0) {
        while ($r=$query->fetch_array()) {
            $begin = new DateTime( $r["llegada"] );
            $end = new DateTime( $r["salida"] );
            $end = $end->modify( '+1 day' ); 
            $interval = new DateInterval('P1D');
            $daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);
            foreach ($daterange as $date) {
            $dates_ar[] = $date->format("Y-m-d");
            }
        }
        ?>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                var disabledDays = <?php echo json_encode($dates_ar)?>;
                var date = new Date();
                 $( "#datepicker9").datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: 'Y-m-d',
                    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
                        var m = date.getMonth() + 1, 
                            d = date.getDate(), 
                            y = date.getFullYear(),
                            strdate = [y,m,d].join('-');
                        if (disabledDays.indexOf(strdate) == -1) {
                            return [true, '', ''];
                        }
                        return [false];
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
        <?php
    }

    else {
?>
        <script>
            $(function() {
                $( "#datepicker9").datepicker({ 
                    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
           });
            });
        </script>
        <?php

    }
?>
```

ty for you time

Comment: For some reason I am completely missing where you are initializing the datepickers.

Comment: @Taplar Is to show the reserved days of that room id, each button has an id, I click the corresponding button and the corresponding datepicker appears.

Comment: reinitialize the date picker after ajax call.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV I put : success:function(html){
    $("#datepicker9").html(html);
    $("#datepicker9").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', });} 
But it does not work

Comment: what is the html you are injecting to $("#datepicker9").html(html) what is the use of that ? can you tell me your requirement??

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV  here  <div class="form-control" style="height: 224px;">
<div type="text" id="datepicker9" name"datepicker9" /></div>
</div>.. In the question is more explained

Comment: still I am unclear ..you have a button and a datepicker in your UI and when you are clicking on the button you have to disable the date picker and some date should be come.from the servcler and that date should be displayed in datepicker is that your requirement???

Comment: datepicker9 is a div and you are trying to inject a date picker in to that,right?? then you habe to initialize the date picker using date picker id not div id.

Comment: @ArunprasanthKV mmm I think yes (sorry I speak spanish for this I am not  clear), I want display the datepicker in the div , I want click in the button and display datepicker in the div , I want click in the other button and the same , the first click is works ...in the div appears the datepicker ..when I click in second or third button the datepicker disappears, and not shows  again the datepicker

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131000/discussion-between-arunprasanth-kv-and-diana-letelier).

Comment: Update $( "#datepicker9").datepicker(); With $(document).on('focus',"#datepicker9", function(){ 
   $(this).datepicker(); });

Comment: can you check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zz9u4/724/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just include  `$("#datepicker9").datepicker("destroy");`
in your ajax success method , also reinitialize the date picker 
check this fiddle 
[Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/zz9u4/727/)